# Error in getGEO command in GEOquery

Tags: r

I`m running the following commands to get the data from GEO

```
library(GEOquery)
gset <- getGEO("GSE9476", GSEMatrix =TRUE, AnnotGPL=TRUE)
```

But, faced the following error

> https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE9nnn/GSE9476/matrix/
>   Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Comment: This might be a bug. Try setting GSEMatrix to False as a temporary solution.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my machine. Related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843204/r-error-when-using-geturl-from-curl-after-site-was-changed). I'd suggest upgrading to the latest GEOquery, RCurl and OpenSSL library if you have not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, How can I upgrade GEOquery,RCurl,..

Comment: @mhd try `install.packages(c("GEOquery", "RCurl"))`.