# R getURL error:1407742E:SSL trying to download a URI

Tags: r, openssl, tls1.2, rcurl, geturl

I am trying to download COVID data in R from a Github site, but I am getting a protocol version error.  This function has worked fine for many months, but now it stopped working.  Can anybody tell me why it is not working?  I can't seem to find any documentation of a solution how to make getURL work.

```
file <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-14-2021.csv")
```

gives the following error :

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Besides, `curlVersion()` doesn't match the expected openssl version installed at the OS level : when I run the command `RCurl::curlVersion()$ssl_version`, I get "OpenSSL/1.0.0o"
I don't know how to update this to version 1.1.1g.

**Context :**

- 64bit PC Windows 10
- R version 4.0.3
- RCurl package version 1.98.1.2
- openssl version 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020  .

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - Error when using getURL from curl after site was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843204/r-error-when-using-geturl-from-curl-after-site-was-changed)

Comment: I looked at that post, but I don't see how that answers my question.  That post is from 2017 and it doesn't have an accepted answer.  getURL was working perfectly up until a week ago and I have all the latest versions of R and Rcurl.  The post just recommends using a different function, but it doesn't explain why getURL is not working as of this week.

Comment: Your problem might be that the website has changed its SSL config (as in the question I mentioned), and that you would need to rebuild RCURL with the latest openssl (as said in a comment). The website only [accepts TLS1.2/1.3](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=raw.githubusercontent.com&s=151.101.0.133&latest). You can add `openssl version` to your question and your exact versions of R/cURL. Right answers aren't always accepted, and users also often forget to answer their own question once they know what's wrong. It's a pity

Comment: Thanks.  I added the version info to my question.  I'm looking for a solution how to fix getURL.  I reloaded the RCurl package, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Which is your openssl version (`openssl version` command) ?

Comment: openssl version 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020.  I'm not sure how to go about rebuilding rCurl to a later openssl version.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but please provide more information on your system. If you are on Linux : `uname -a` and `cat /etc/*release*` . We'll then see if I start a bounty, it's not obvious to reproduce this problem.

Comment: My computer is a 64bit PC Windows 10.  Are you saying that you don't get the same error if you run that code I put in the post?

Comment: Indeed, I don't get the same error and I am probably using a very different install method for installing this software (on a Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another broken R package, poorly documented, not maintained, doesn't taking any constructive feedback and so on.
Unfortunately there are similar questions without real answers other than suggesting to try another (better) package like [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html) .I can't give a better one.

Old SSL servers accepting TLS 1.0 would work for example :

```
getURL("https://www.ietf.org", sslversion=4L)
```

But your website only allows TLS 1.2 & 1.3, and trying TLS 1.2 gives an unsupported error on the client side, whatever site we try

```
getURL("https://www.ietf.org", sslversion=5L)
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Unsupported SSL protocol version
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the exactely same problem, with curlversion 1.98-1.2 SSL version "OpenSSL/1.0.0o" ; R version 4.0.2 ; Windows10 ;

Comment: ```file <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-14-2021.csv")```

Comment: it's better to edit your own Answer than posting this comment. Moreover, consider voting on the question if you are facing the very same issue.