# Unable to access directory of HTML site using R (RCurl package)

Tags: r, http, ftp, rcurl

I am trying to access the following http directory of weather data using the RCurl package in R:

http://ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/

within each directory for each year is a unique list of weather stations.

I can access any specific dataset like this

```
url = 'http://ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/1932/03005099999.csv'
data = read.csv(url)
```

However, I can't automate this process without knowing what files are within each directory. I've tried using the RCurl package to get a list of all the files within, but always get errors:

```
url = 'http://ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/'
getURL(url)
```

This gives me the following output saying the address has changed (to an https address)

```
[1] "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>\n<p>The document has moved <a href=\"https://ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/\">here</a>.</p>\n</body></html>\n"
```

Changing the address to the https url indicated gives this error

```
url = 'https://ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/'
getURL(url)

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I tried replacing the https: with ftps: and ftp: Doing so gives me a time out error.

Any thoughts on getting the directory printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the server only supports requests using TLS version 1.2 and your [RCurl does not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843204/r-error-when-using-geturl-from-curl-after-site-was-changed).

You might be able to achieve what you want using `httr` and `rvest`. For example, to get a tibble listing the files in the 1929 directory:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

url1 <- "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-summary-of-the-day/access/1929"
page_data <- GET(url1)

files <- content(page_data, as = "parsed") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]]

files

# A tibble: 24 x 4
   Name               `Last modified`    Size  Description
   <chr>              <chr>              <chr> <lgl>      
 1 ""                 ""                 ""    NA         
 2 "Parent Directory" ""                 "-"   NA         
 3 "03005099999.csv"  "2019-01-19 12:37" "20K" NA         
 4 "03075099999.csv"  "2019-01-19 12:37" "20K" NA         
 5 "03091099999.csv"  "2019-01-19 12:37" "17K" NA         
 6 "03159099999.csv"  "2019-01-19 12:37" "20K" NA         
 7 "03262099999.csv"  "2019-01-19 12:37" "20K" NA         
 8 "03311099999.csv"  "2019-01-19 12:37" "19K" NA         
 9 "03379099999.csv"  "2019-01-19 12:37" "33K" NA         
10 "03396099999.csv"  "2019-01-19 12:37" "21K" NA         
# ... with 14 more rows
```